# EF Core 6 objects dont load parent or child entities

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Referring to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships):

From what I understand, EF Core 6 object relationships are automagically mapped if your objects are defined per the example below:

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DeviceGroupId { get; set; }

    public DeviceGroup DeviceGroup { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set;}
}
```

However, its not working for me.

In my DB tables:

- `Device.Id` and `DeviceGroup.Id` are primary keys (integer, identity)
- `Device.DeviceGroupId` is an integer with foreign key defined between `Device.DeviceGroupId` and `DeviceGroup.Id`

I understand you can also specify these relationships explicitly by override the `OnModelCreating` of the DbContext, but I'd prefer to understand why my implementation above isnt working.

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: Thank you a lot Alex. What is the default loading style for EF Core 6?

Comment: Eager Loading with Include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core by default provides **LazyLoading**, you have to use **Eager Loading** if you want to include all the related entities. That is done using `.Include()` method.
Which can also be chained using `.ThenInclude()`.

Comment: By default `LazyLoading` is disabled unless you explicitly define `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`.

Comment: By default EF Core provides **no** loading of the related data, except for navigations to owned entities or explicitly configured for `.AutoInclude()`